# Setting selected value does not trigger SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have a situation where I need the `SelectedIndexChanged` to fire when I programatically select an item. Here is what I am doing.

I load a dropdownlist from the database on `FormLoad` and I am setting the value of the drop down based on information passed in the query string like this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["nat"] != null)
{
    ddlTriggers.ClearSelection();
    ddlTriggers.Items.FindByValue(
            Request.QueryString["nat"].ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```

This does work correctly in that it takes the id from the querystring and matches it up to a particular item in the drop down. The issue is that just by setting `.selected=true` does not fire the `selectedIndexChanged` event. I am trying to set some labels when the selected index is changed.

Some suggestions showed manually calling `selectedIndexChanged` like this:

```
ddlCommonTasks_SelectedIndexChanged(ddlTriggers, EventArgs.Empty);
```

but then that resets the `selectedIndex` and shows me the label for the 1st item in the drop down which of course doesnt help me any.

Any suggestions.

Comment: How about you transfer the code you do inside of the SelectedIndexChanged event to a method and then call the method inside of the SelectedIndexChanged event and at the end of the method that is the one that changes the selection programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the selected index on post back or on page load at server. The event will not fire. What you can do is to take stuff in `SelectedIndexChanged` handler and refactor it into separate method which can be called whenever you update value like:

```
ddlCommonTasks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    PerformIndexChangedAction(ddl);
}

private void PerformIndexChangedAction(DropDownList ddl)
{
    lblTest.Text=ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Modify the code as follows:

```
var nat = Request.QueryString["nat"];
if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(nat))
{
    ddlTriggers.ClearSelection();
    ddlTriggers.Items.FindByValue(nat).Selected = true;
    PerformIndexChangedAction(ddlTriggers);
}
```

Comment: Nice Answer. That makes total sense now. I didnt realize that if setting the drop down on post back it wouldnt fire the selectedIndexChanged. I will update the code and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right in assuming that you have registered a handler for the selectedIndexChanged event, you could simply call the same function that you registered as a handler for your event.

If you've registered your handler like this:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

You could instead define your function elsewhere, and pass that:

```
function handler() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
}

$(".target").change(handler);
```

Now, in your existing code just call your handler function:

```
if (Request.QueryString["nat"] != null)
{
    ddlTriggers.ClearSelection();
    ddlTriggers.Items.FindByValue(Request.QueryString["nat"].ToString()).Selected = true;
    handler();
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer however that assumes I was using jQuery. This is a specific C# question. I never registered my handler so that is probably why it didnt work as expected.